# missing rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rubygems, rake

I have ran gem install rails and am running 2.3.4

but i am missing some rake tasks like 'db' and 'gems'

if i run rake -T i get the following tasks.  How can i get all the others ?

> rake apache2 # Build Apache 2 module
>
> rake clean # Remove compiled files
>
> rake clobber # Remove all generated
>   files
>
> rake default # Build everything
>
> rake doc # Generate all documentation
>
> rake doxygen # Generate Doxygen C++
>   API documentation if ...
>
> rake doxygen:clobber # Remove
>   generated Doxygen C++ API documenta...
>
> rake doxygen:force # Force generation
>   of Doxygen C++ API docume...
>
> rake fakeroot # Create a fakeroot,
>   useful for building nat...
>
> rake nginx # Build Nginx helper server
>
> rake package # Build all the packages
>
> rake package:clean # Remove package
>   products
>
> rake package:debian # Create a Debian
>   package
>
> rake package:force # Force a rebuild
>   of the package files
>
> rake package:gem # Build the gem file
>   passenger-2.2.4.gem
>
> rake rdoc # Build the rdoc HTML Files
>
> rake rdoc:clobber # Remove rdoc
>   products
>
> rake rdoc:force # Force a rebuild of
>   the RDOC files
>
> rake sloccount # Run 'sloccount' to
>   see how much code Passe...
>
> rake test # Run all unit tests and
>   integration tests
>
> rake test:cxx # Run unit tests for the
>   Apache 2 and Nginx ...
>
> rake test:integration # Run all
>   integration tests
>
> rake test:integration:apache2 # Run
>   Apache 2 integration tests
>
> rake test:integration:nginx # Run
>   Nginx integration tests
>
> rake test:oxt # Run unit tests for the
>   OXT library
>
> rake test:rcov # Run coverage tests
>   for the Ruby libraries
>
> rake test:restart # Run the 'restart'
>   integration test infinit...
>
> rake test:ruby

If anyone knows why this has happened, how i can fix it or anything else that could help, please let me know

thanks alot
rick

Comment: One question should be enough!

Comment: Are you running `rake -T` from within your apps root folder?

Comment: What Anand asked ... the tasks are local to the folder for your rails application. Run it from there and then get back to us.

Comment: This looks like the rake tasks from inside the rails lib directory not RAILS_ROOT. Or some gem directory, not sure which. The nginx/apache2 tests seem to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

seems like the rake tasks for mod_rails.
To run the tests for rails go to rails folder.

Comment: what do you mean by "rails folder"? I'm in my rails app directory but I don't see any of the db tasks.